# Visual Studio 2013/2015 C++ Item Templates Missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make some simple Item Templates for Visual Studio 2013 (Professional) C++ projects, but Visual Studio seems to be fighting with me.  I started using the `File -> Export Template...` wizard, which completed and generated a zip file, but alas, the new template was nowhere to be seen on the `Add New Item` dialog, so I started manually editing it to see if I could fix it.

Here is my test `.vstemplate` file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>test</DefaultName>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Description>Test item template.</Description>
    <ProjectType>VC</ProjectType>
    <!--<SortOrder>10</SortOrder>-->
    <Icon>icon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.h" ReplaceParameters="true">test.h</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I've tried using both `VC` and `VisualC` for `<ProjectType>` and placing the template in various folders, in both zipped and expanded forms.

After changing `<ProjectType>` to `CSharp` and creating a C# project it shows up immediately.  Interestingly, if the `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#` directory is empty, the template will now show up if it is in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates` or `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C++ Project` directories, but if a copy of it is also in the `Visual C#` directory it shows up twice in the new item dialog...

I know there was a bug with the Visual Studio 2013 Express RC where the New Item dialog wouldn't show any templates at all, even the built-in ones, so I'm thinking this might be a bug in Visual Studio, or just another example of Microsoft's disturbing disregard for C++.

Is there something I'm missing here or is this a bug with VS2013?  If so does anyone know of any workaround?

Edit: This problem still exists in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Comment: It is work in progress, C++ item templates still use the legacy format that work with the [code wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xz4cw2.aspx).  Maybe next version.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the info.  Seems like they should give you a warning when you use the export template tool to make a VC template if they're not supported at all...  Maybe by the time C++11 is fully supported this will be fixed... around 10 years from now in all liklihood.  Anyway make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Wow 10 months and still no answer.Even I am looking for a solution

Comment: Tried with VS2015 Preview, same situation. The template doesn't show up.

Comment: This is a problem for me too. I've raised the issue on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1094450

Answer (score 5):

Having the same problem. The workaround that works for me is to use the VS2013 Express edition, where C++ Item templates work just fine (just like they did in VS2012 Pro/Express). I have no clue why this handy functionality has been removed from the Pro edition but keeps on working in the free express edition.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It's silly that one needs to have multiple versions of the IDE installed to get this working. Still this was a really helpful post! I'm up-voting this answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

My first adventure with VS templates and I run into this! Jackpot!

After a few hours of fiddling around I am now able to add my own templates, at least in VS Community 2013. I *think* the trick is to add `<TemplateGroupID>WinRT-Common</TemplateGroupID>`. For reference, this item template shows up for me in an empty C++ project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>GameEngine Core Class</Name>
    <Description>Creates a header and source file for a new GameEngine Core class.</Description>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
    <TemplateGroupID>WinRT-Common</TemplateGroupID>
    <ProjectType>VC</ProjectType>
    <DefaultName>GameEngineClassName</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cpp" ReplaceParameters="true" OpenInEditor="true">GameEngineClass.cpp</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.h" ReplaceParameters="true" OpenInEditor="true">GameEngineClass.h</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

For `TemplateGroupID`, the default (`VC-Native`) nor `VC-Windows` seem to work ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/extensibility/templategroupid-element-visual-studio-templates)'s the full list). I'm not sure what the further implications of putting `WinRT-Common` there may be. It's not even listed.

Some more details: I started with experimenting on the `ComputeShader.vstemplate` that comes with VS2013, putting it in the templates folder and modifying the file until it is what it is now. Somewhere along the way I realized it's quite important to put everything in a .zip file, even though it seems to work initially, because Visual Studio will eventually behave very odd when it comes to detecting the templates (it was quite frustrating before I realized that). I guess it has to do with the cache.