# How do I create a Visual Studio 2013 template to produce a .cpp and .h file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to create a set of templates so I don't have to re-adjust the .h and .cpp files the Visual Studio class wizard produces for a new C++ class each time.

I've created a .cpp and .h file as a template but visual studio doesn't allow me to export both as a singe template item.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: we're using an extension to do exactly that. would be nice if there were a way to solve this in templates.

Comment: What extension are you using?

Comment: If you want, you can add it as a .hpp file and have both the prototype and the implementation in the same template file.

Comment: @gmanolache - Our coding standard explicitly states that we should separate prototype from implementation so that's not an option. If I have to manually create the .cpp file and pull in all the bits I need each time that rather defeats the object here...

Comment: Have you made it work [even with single file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20858102/4074081)? According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx) - `You cannot export templates for C++ projects.` Recommended way of creating multi-item template is to [manually edit archive exported by wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247113%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: No I hadn't got that far as I'd fallen at the first hurdle of the objective I was trying to achieve. I'll give that link a go...

Comment: ...and you're right - that doesn't work either.